# I am able to write a javax.jws.WebService successfully. However I do not know exactly how to write a web service client for same in java

Tags: web-services, spring, jaxb, webservice-client

I have written Webservice in java which has successfully created WSDL. I am stuck in writing a webservice client for my webservice in java. I would like to use my webservice from some jsp classes. How do i do it?

```
@WebService
public interface AddService {
    double getMultipicationResult(double M1, double M2);
}

 @WebService(endpointInterface = "com.sample.AddService")
    public class AddServiceImpl implements AddService {
        public AddServiceImpl() {
        }
        @Override
        public double getMultipicationResult(double M1, double M2) {
            M1 = M1*M2;
            return M1;
        }
    }
```

I have written the client something like :-

```
public class AddServiceClient {
    private AddServiceClient() {
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
    {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"SpringClientWebServices.xml"});
        AddService  client = (AddService)context.getBean("client");
        double response = 0.0;
        response = client.getMultipicationResult(10.0, 20.5);
    }
}
```

and SpringClientWebServices.xml is as follows :-

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd      
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="client" class="com.sample.AddService" 
          factory-bean="clientFactory" factory-method="create"/>

    <bean id="clientFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceClass" value="com.sample.AddService"/>
        <property name="address" value="http://localhost:8080/sample/services/Addition"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I am getting exception as follows:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean] for bean with name 'clientFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringClientWebServices.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are missing the CXF jars as evident from the ClassNotFoundException. Please include the cxf jars.

Second regarding using the service in JSPs then you have to first initialize the Spring container via web.xml and not via main method. Use Spring MVC and implement controller which makes calls to webservice and provide data to the JSP.

Comment: will surely check for missing jars. Since the architecture I am working on is following Struts and spring integration. I would like to know is there any way to call webservice from servlet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consume a service directly from the JSP, consider a JavaScript client like mentioned: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/javascript-client-samples.html

I prefer to use a jar that contains the service interface and create a dynamic Spring client using CXF and Spring in a separate jar, then bring in both f those dependencies. This is also documented in the CXF site.